# Hibernate inheritance made simple?? Three class hierarchy, one concrete table - how?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have three classes:

xyz/url/core/datastore/ObjectBase.java
xyz/url/core/test/hibernate/BaseClass.java
xyz/url/core/test/hibernate/ChildClass.java

Their code:

ObjectBase

```
package xyz.url.core.datastore;

import java.util.Date;

public abstract class ObjectBase {
    private final long  m_id;
    private final long  m_version;

    private final Date  m_creation_time;

    public ObjectBase() {
        this.m_id = 0;
        this.m_version = 0;

        this.m_creation_time = new Date();
    }

    public long get_id() {
        return this.m_id;
    }

    public long get_version() {
        return this.m_version;
    }

    public Date get_creation_time() {
        return this.m_creation_time;
    }
}
```

BaseClass

```
package xyz.url.core.test.hibernate;

import java.util.Date;

import xyz.url.core.datastore.ObjectBase;

public abstract class BaseClass extends ObjectBase {

    private final Date  m_another_time;

    public BaseClass() {
        this.m_another_time = new Date();
    }

    public void say_something() {
        final Class<?> my_class = this.getClass();
        final String output = String.format(
                "Hello from the `%s` class! My id is %d!", my_class.getName(),
                this.get_id());
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

ChildClass

```
package xyz.url.core.test.hibernate;

public class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
    private String  m_text;

    public ChildClass(final String text) {
        this.m_text = text;
    }

    public void set_text(final String text) {
        this.m_text = text;
    }

    public String get_text() {
        return this.m_text;
    }
}
```

Currently I use implicit polymorphism; I have one HBM.XML file for the only "concrete" class (`ChildClass`), named "ChildClass.hbm.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="xyz.url.core.test.hibernate"
    default-access="field">

    <class name="ChildClass" table="child_class">
        <!-- Attributes of ObjectBase -->
        <id name="m_id" column="id">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>

        <version name="m_version" column="version" type="long" />

        <property name="m_creation_time" column="creation_time" type="date" />

        <!-- Attributes of BaseClass -->
        <property name="m_another_time" column="another_time" type="date" />

        <!-- Attributes of ChildClass -->
        <property name="m_text" column="text" type="string" />
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

See the above? I aggregate all the attributes of the three classes into one table.

**I want to do the same as above, get one table as above ("child_class"), but break it into three HBM.XML files.**

I was hoping Hibernate (v4.1) supports some sort of an **"import" keyword**, so I can create three HBM.XML files, one for each class, and link them all into one.
Unfortunately they got "too smart" and made things a lot more complicated. If I'm wrong, enlighten me please!

Take note that `ObjectBase` and `BaseClass` are `abstract` classes.

Another thing worth mentioning is that when I get an object from the database I know exactly what type it should be, so maybe I should not use "discriminators"...?..

Here is some console output when I test what I **currently have**, and I wish it stays this way, I mean, one table is created, one table is being fetched when reading (instead of the "join strategy" I've read in Hibernate's docs):

```
Hibernate: 
    drop table child_class if exists
Hibernate: 
    create table child_class (
        id bigint not null,
        version bigint not null,
        creation_time date,
        another_time date,
        text varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    )
APR 14, 2012 8:49:47 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
Hibernate: 
    select
        max(id) 
    from
        child_class
Hibernate: 
    /* insert xyz.url.core.test.hibernate.ChildClass
        */ insert 
        into
            child_class
            (version, creation_time, another_time, text, id) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

**Again, all I want is to break my HBM.XML to three different files so I don't have to write the same properties in every concrete class's descriptor. That's all.**

Thank you!

Comment: Looks more like its you who is trying to be to smart. But not smart enough to RTFM: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html

Comment: @barsju You DEFINITELY did NOT read the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`union-subclass` is all I needed. Simple, OOP-like inheritance.

Answer (score -1):

*did you even read the link barsju posted in his comment?*

`9.1.5. Table per concrete class` is most probably what you want. And there is also `<!ENTITY allproperties SYSTEM "allproperties.xml">` mentioned to import xml.

Comment: Down vote for the bad attitude you and barsju show me. Yea, I might sound like a dick, but you're really welcome to check my SO profile and see how I personally answer (help) people. I do my best. In your (and barsju's) case it sounds like you're forced to write something.

Comment: you are right that barsju has been rude in his comment. Also he has given the link to the right answer. i didn't mean to offend, only want to say that the answer is already given. "check my SO profile and see how I personally answer (help) people" dito

Comment: Ok, well you know what they say; When you already know something - it's easy (to locate). Pointing to the manual, which I've already read about twice, is not giving the answer, even though you mentioned "Table per concrete class". My problem was probably that the what I was looking for is scattered among other similar things. Anyway, maybe next time...